# Approximate Order Statistics for lognormal variables

Tags: expected-value, lognormal-distribution, order-statistics

Are there any known formulas that approximate the expected value of the maximum of $N$ i.i.d. lognormal random variables?

I am looking for something similar to:
[Approximate order statistics for normal random variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9001/approximate-order-statistics-for-normal-random-variables)

But in general any useful info on the expected value will be appreciated.

Comment: The logarithm is a monotonic transformation, so you could simply work on the logged data, which are normally distributed (so [your link](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/9001/1352) applies), then exponentiate the order statistics. Or what am I missing?

Comment: @StephanKolassa That is what I thought, but I'm wondering how to get at the expected value as $E[e^{X}]$ does not equal $e^{E[X]}$ generally.

Comment: Yes, of course, you are right. Perhaps [the beta-F distribution](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/9010/1352) would help, and maybe there is something about its exponential...

Comment: Do you only care about the maximum, or are you interested in higher order statistics from the lognormal in general?

Comment: @jbowman At this point I care only about the maximum. Others would be nice, of course, but even maximum will be helpful.

Comment: This is really a duplicate of http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/213753/expectation-of-two-identical-lognormal-distributions/213812#213812     My answer there contains a link to a paper with the full solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not know of any standard approximate formulas for this. So I tried the following standard technique.

Let $X_1,...,X_N$ be $N$ iid log-normal random variables. Let $Y=\max_i X_i$ be their maximum. Now we need to find $E[Y].$ Let $F_Y(y)$ be the cdf of $Y$ and $F_X(x)$ be the cdf of any $X_i$'s. Then,

\begin{eqnarray}
F_Y(y) &=& P(Y \leq y) = P(\max_i X_i \leq y) \\
&=& P(\cap_i \{X_i \leq y\}) \\
&=& \prod_i P(X_i \leq y) = F_X(y)^N
\end{eqnarray}

Since $X_i$'s are iid. Now note that $X_i$'s are non-negative random variables and so is $Y.$ For any non-negative RV we can express its expectation in terms if its cdf as follows. You can find its derivation [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10159/find-expected-value-using-cdf).

$$
E[Y] = \int_0^\infty (1-F_Y(y))dy = \int_0^\infty (1-F_X(y)^N)dy
$$

Now for any log-normal random variable $F_X(x) = \Phi\left(\frac{\ln x - \mu}{\sigma} \right),$ where $\Phi$ is the cdf of the standard normal distribution.
Therefore

$$
E[Y] = \int_0^\infty \left(1-\Phi\left(\frac{\ln y - \mu}{\sigma} \right)^N\right)dy
$$

Till now we have an exact formula for $E[Y].$ All I can think of now is a numerical integration to approximately compute $E[Y].$ The function $\Phi$ is well approximated and there are library functions for it. For a given $\mu,\sigma,N$ we can approximately compute $E[Y]$ using standard [numerical integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration) techniques.

Comment: Thanks - I am looking for an analytical closed form approximation (it'll go into a game theory model). The numerical approach is quite obvious.

Comment: @Ron but what do you want from closed form? If you want to calculate derivatives you still can do it by differentiating the integral by parameter and then calculating numerically the resulting integral.

Comment: I guess I don't see the benefit of an approximate closed form solution either, as opposed to an accurate numeric value. As @a-rodin suggested you can always approximate using a Taylor series, by taking derivative of the integral and numerically computing the Taylor coefficients.

Comment: I will need derivatives with respect to N, which indeed I can take. The issue is the error function/normal PDF.

Taking taylor approximations is a good point - I'll just do that.

Thanks guys!