# How many random samples before you're not surprised by an extreme value?

Tags: probability, sampling, extreme-value

Suppose I look at a collection of 10 students and calculate the mean and standard deviation of their GPAs. No one in this group has a 4.0. Then I take another 10 students at random and find that one of them has a 4.0. How surprised should I be by this? Knowing the mean and standard deviation of the first group, how many non-4.0 students should I expect to see before finding one with a 4.0?

Edit: In hindsight, I can see that maybe the discrete nature of a GPA calculation and the fact that a 4.0 represents a maximum possible bound may complicate the issue. If it simplifies things, assume continuously valued variables with no upper or lower bounds.

Links to suggested references are welcome!

Comment: It sounds a little like you would be interested in a non-parametric prediction limit based on a sample size, a mean, a standard deviation, *and a presumed maximum and minimum possible value.* That would be difficult to compute (and you might find no literature on it): usually, such limits are based on the sample size and either the maximum of the data or the top few values in the data.  Other limits can be obtained by adopting *parametric models* of the distribution and/or assuming a prior distribution.

Comment: A broad answer to this broad question is that you need on average $1/p$ simulations to observe an event of probability $p$.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to look at this, first, say you have independent observations from the same continuous distribution with cdf (cumulative distribution function) $F$, $X_1, \dotsc, X_n$.  Then one question could be the expected value of the maximum of the $n$ observations, $X_{(n)}$. That question is answered by expected value of the order statistics, see for instance [Approximate Order Statistics for lognormal variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/214103/approximate-order-statistics-for-lognormal-variables)  or  [Expectation of maximum of i.i.d Weibull random variables?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/286224/expectation-of-maximum-of-i-i-d-weibull-random-variables/286227#286227)  (or search this site).  A very crude approximation is just taking the corresponding quantile $q=n/(n-1)$ of the quantile function of $F$, that is, $F^{-1}(q)$.

Another viewpoint is following the comment by @Xi'an, if you are waiting for an event of probability $p$ (say, $p=0.1$ if you are waiting for an observation in the highest decile of the distribution).  If $p$ is small and $n$ is large, the number of events in the class have a poisson distribution (approximately) with parameter $np$.  So we want the probability that the n umber of events is one or larger, $P(X \ge 1)$. For a poisson with parameter $1=n\cdot \frac1n$ we have (with help from R)

```
1-ppois(0, 1)
[1] 0.6321206
```

so with number of observations $\frac1n$ the probability of at least one event is 0.63.  If we double the sample size to $\frac2n$ we get

```
1-ppois(0, 2)
[1] 0.8646647
```

so the probability increases to 0.86