# Expectation of maximum of i.i.d Weibull random variables?

Tags: probability, order-statistics, weibull-distribution

I'm trying to find an asymptotic approximation for the expectation of the maximum of $n$ Weibull random variables $X_i \sim Weibull(\lambda,\beta)$ when $\beta < 1/2$ and $n$ is large. From simulations, I'm getting that

$$E[max(X_1,...,X_n) ]  \approx  A n^{c}$$ for some constant $A$ and constant $c < 1$, but I'm not sure how to prove something like this.

Are there any well-known approximations for the expectation of the maximum of Weibull random variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An exact formula is given by ["A note on order statistics from Weibull distribution"](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03461238.1981.10413737) by Balakrishnan and Joshi. Define 
$$J(p,0) =  \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{\beta}\right)}{\lambda\beta p^{1/\beta}}$$
with
$$J(p,m) = J(p,m-1) - J(p+1,m-1) $$
Define $\alpha_n$ as the expected value of the $n$th smallest sample. Then the expected value of the smallest sample is
$$\alpha_1 = J(1,0)$$
and for larger samples is
$$ \alpha_r = \alpha_{r-1} + \binom{N-1}{r-1}J(N-r+1,r-1)$$

Comment: Thanks! I also found the following slightly more explicit formula for the expectation of the maximum on a book by Chin-Diew Lai called "Generalized Weibull Distributions" 

$$ E[max(X_1,...,X_n)] = n \Gamma(1+1/\beta) \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{i} (-1)^i (\frac{1}{i+1})^{1 + 1/\beta}$$